# Angular Test case for image map resizer

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, automated-tests, image-resizing, angular-test

I'm using the image-map-resizer [plugin](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer) for a responsive image mapping. And I need help in writing testcase for it.

This is my html : 
`<img src="...." width="100%"  usemap="#usaMap" (load)="imageResized();">`

This is my TS file :

```
declare function imageMapResize(): void;

@Component({...

})
...
imageResized() {
  imageMapResize(); // Javascript function in imageMapResizer.min.js 
}
```

and this is my test file :

```
it('should call imageMapResize() on imageResized method', () => {
   spyOn(component, 'imageMapResize').and.callThrough();
   component.imageResized();
   expect(component.imageMapResize).toHaveBeenCalled()
});
```

And this is the error that I'm getting on compilation :

```
Argument of type '"imageMapResize"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"ngOnInit" | "currentMap" | "mapDataObj" | "imageResized"'.

 -- spyOn(component, 'imageMapResize').and.callThrough();
```

I know it's pretty simple, but I recently started unit testing

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you can only spy on public methods and the error tells you that the only methods you can spy on are: `'"ngOnInit" | "currentMap" | "mapDataObj" | "imageResized"'`.

I see you are spying on `imageMapResize` and that's not a public method.

I would do this if I were you.

```
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
....
it('should call imageResized on load', () => {
  // make the CSS selector more specific if there are multiple images
  const resizeSpy = spyOn(component, 'imageResized');
  const img = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('img'));
  img.triggerEventHandler('load', {});
  expect(resizeSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this solution did not work, I had to skip this particular Test case